Prove an inequality alike the Rosenthal's Inequality
I am given a homework assignment to show that
Let $\left\{X_{i}, 1 \leq i \leq n\right\}$ be independent random variables with $\mathrm{E}\left(X_{i}\right)=0$ and $\mathrm{E}\left|X_{i}\right|^{p}<\infty$, where $1<p<3$. Prove that
$$
\mathrm{E}\left|S_{n}\right|^{p} \leq 2^{2-p} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \mathrm{E}\left|X_{i}\right|^{p} \quad \text { for } 1<p<2
$$
and
$$
\mathrm{E}\left|S_{n}\right|^{p} \leq(p-1) B_{n}^{p}+\sum_{i=1}^{n} \mathrm{E}\left|X_{i}\right|^{p} \quad \text { for } 2<p \leq 3
$$
where $B_{n}^{2}=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \mathrm{E}\left|X_{i}\right|^{2}$.

The conditions for this problem is the same as the Rosenthal's inequality, which basically states that
$$
(ES_n^2)^{\frac{p}{2}}+\sum_{i=1}^n E|X_i|^p \lesssim_pE|S_n|^p\lesssim_p (ES_n^2)^{\frac{p}{2}}+\sum_{i=1}^n E|X_i|^p.
$$
And the proof adopts the Hoeffding's inequality.

As for the first case of this problem, where $1<p<2$, my initial thought is to show that
$$
E|S_n|^p \leq E(|X_1|+\cdots+|X_n|)^p \leq 2^{2-p}\sum_{i=1}^n E|X_i|^p.
$$
The above inequality holds when $p=1$ and $p=2$. Yet I am not sure whether it is still valid in $1<p<2$.
I also have a thought of proving this using $P(|S_n|\geq t),t>0$, however, given the form of the inequality, I think the former approach is more likely.
When $2<p<3$,  as $p>2$,
$$
\begin{aligned}
 & (\sum_{i=1}^n E|X_i|^p)\leq \sum_{i=1}^n (E|X_i|^2)^{\frac{p}{2}} \\
 & \Rightarrow (\sum_{i=1}^n E|X_i|^p)^{\frac{1}{p}}\leq (\sum_{i=1}^n (E|X_i|^2)^{\frac{p}{2}})^{\frac{1}{p}} = \|(E|X_i|^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}\|_{\ell^p}\leq \|(E|X_i|^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}\|_{\ell^2} = (\sum_{i=1}^n E|X_i|^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}.
\end{aligned}
$$
Hence $\sum_{i=1}^n E|X_i|^p \leq B_n^p$ and it suffices to show that
$$
E|X_1+\cdots +X_n|^p \leq p\cdot E(\sum_{i=1}^n|X_i|^p),
$$
The inequality holds for $p=2$. Again, I have no idea whether it holds for $p>2$. Any help would be appreciated.

In which context did this homework assignment appear? What have you covered before? Usually, an approach consists in using induction and an expansion of |1+t|^p$.

@DavideGiraudo, the assignment appears in a section discussing several inequalities regarding partial sums, like the Hoeffding's Inequality, Rosentha's and some others concerning the symmetrization techniques. There is a question before asking us to show that $|1+x|^p\leq 1+px+2^{2-p}|x|^p$ for $1\leq p\leq 2$. Please check a previous question I have asked. I have problem using the expansion, due to the existence of the absolute value here.

@DavideGiraudo, thank you for your hint, I think I could prove the first case where $1<p<2$, by the inequality $|a+b|^p\leq |a|^p +p\cdot \operatorname{sgn}(a)|a|^{p-1}b +2^{2-p}|b|^p$ and the induction on $n$.

Both inequality can be proven by induction, once we get a convenient inequality for $\lvert a+b\rvert^p$ in terms of $\lvert a\rvert^p$, $\lvert b\rvert^p$ and other terms. Indeed, for $1<p\leqslant 2$,
$$
\lvert a+b\rvert^p\leqslant \lvert a\rvert^p+p\operatorname{sgn}(a)\lvert a\rvert^{p-1}b+2^{2-p}\lvert b\rvert^p.
$$
Applying this with $a=S_n$ and $b=X_{n+1}$ and writing $M_n:=\mathbb E\left[\lvert S_n\rvert^p\right]$ gives, after having taken the expectation,
$$
M_{n+1}\leqslant M_n+p\mathbb E\left[\operatorname{sgn}(S_n)\lvert S_n\rvert^{p-1}X_{n+1}\right]+2^{2-p}\mathbb E\left[\lvert X_{n+1}\rvert^p\right].
$$
Using that $X_{n+1}$ is centered and independence between $\operatorname{sgn}(S_n)\lvert S_n\rvert^{p-1}$ and $X_{n+1}$, we get
$$ M_{n+1}\leqslant M_n+2^{2-p}\mathbb E\left[\lvert X_{n+1}\rvert^p\right] $$
and the result follows by induction.
In the case $2<p\leqslant 3$, a use of Taylor's formula with integral remainder and sub-additivity of the map $u\in [0,\infty)\mapsto u^{p-2}$ gives
$$
\lvert a+b\rvert^p\leqslant \lvert a\rvert^p+p\lvert a\rvert^{p-1}\operatorname{sgn}(a)b+\frac{p(p-1)}2\lvert a\rvert^{p-2}b^2+\lvert b\rvert^p.
$$
Applying this with $a=X_{n+1}$ and $b=S_n$ then integrating reduces to find a bound for
$$
\frac{p(p-1)}2\mathbb E\left[\lvert X_{n+1}\rvert^{p-2}\right]B_n^2.
$$
